# Obtaining the identity of the app pool

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

**Given a specific app pool, is there a way to get the identity associated with it?**

[image]

In the image above, I am trying to get the "NetworkService".

I've tried the following:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\DeFaultAppPool|Select-Object *
```

However, identity is nowhere to be found:

[image]

**is there a way to get the identity associated with it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found under `processModel.identityType`:

```
(Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool).processModel.identityType
```